# how to use string template in string.xml of kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use globalization in my Android project, Now I need a string like `"name ${user.name} \n sex ${user.sex}"` in my `string.xml`,  how to use it in `.kt file` in addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can not set string in this way in `strings.xml`. What you can do is set `name %s \nsex %s` and get string value like `context.getString(R.string.resId, user.name, user.sex)`

Comment: If you found this correct, then please accept this answer.